# iOS Safari Javascript not working but works on Desktop and Android

Tags: javascript, ios, dom, safari

The purpose of this script is to hide and show figure elements depending on a query string. e.g, website.com/repair-catalog?catalog=brand1.

This script works on Desktop and from what I've seen Android devices. But on iOS Safari, the script doesn't seem to work.

If I did visited: `website.com/repair-catalog?catalog=brand1`.

the `case "brand1"` would kick off and would proceed to show only figures with innerText of Headphones, earbuds, and speakers. And hides the other figures. Once again, this works in Desktop and Android. But when I visit the page on iOS Safari, the `case "brand1"` is running, but instead of showing Headphones, earbuds, and speakers... the script automatically goes into the `default` case.

Why doesn't this script work on Safari iOS as it does in Desktop and Android? It shouldn't hide all the figures. Only the figures that don't match within the cases.

I've attempted to rewrite my script so that it doesn't use `URLSearchParams`, `switch statements`, and `forEach` loops. But still I end up having the same result of it working on Desktop and Android but not Safari iOS. On Safari iOS, default case is ran all the time.

Note, I've checked the `typeof figure.innerText` and it is a string, which means it should match `case "brand1"`. It does this correctly on Desktop and android.

```
const catalogQuery = new URLSearchParams(document.location.search);
const catalogType = catalogQuery.get("catalog")
const nodeList = document.querySelectorAll(".figure-wrapper a figure");
const x = [...nodeList];
try {
    if (catalogType !== null) {
        switch (catalogType) {
            case "brand1":
                x.forEach(figure => {
                    switch (figure.innerText) {
                        case "HEADPHONES":
                            figure.style.display = "block";
                            figure.parentElement.attributes[0].value = "/headphones";
                            break;
                        case "EARBUDS":
                            figure.style.display = "block";
                            figure.parentElement.attributes[0].value = "/earbuds";
                            break;
                        case "SPEAKERS":
                            figure.style.display = "block";
                            figure.parentElement.attributes[0].value = "/speakers";
                            break;
                        default: 
                            figure.parentElement.style.display = "none";
                            break;
                    }
                });
                break;
           default:
                location.href = "/repair-catalog";
                break;
        }
    }
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`URLSearchParams` is not supported in all versions of safari or older browsers.

please use a  polyfill or  split the url params and use the query param values .

Comment: URLSearchParams is not the issue. I've tried swapping it out for `const catalogType = document.location.search.split("=")[1];` and it still doesn't run properly on mobile.